# If F is closed show F is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

This question was left as an optional exercise in my lecture notes and says the argument uses compactness. I came up with an argument which doesn't require compactness and I wondering if it is correct.

Let $F=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack$

For each n,

$\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack 
\subseteq O_n$, 
where $O_n=(a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_n)
\cup(a_n,b_n)
\cup(b_n,b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$

As $\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack$ is defined as $(a_n,b_n)\cup\{a_n,b_n\}$ this implies

$(O_n\backslash\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack)
=(a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_n)
\cup(b_n,b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2})
\backslash\{a_n,b_n\}$

Thus,

$m_{*}(O_n\backslash\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack)
\leq m_{*}(a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_n)
+ m_{*}(b_n,b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2})
- m_{*}\{a_n\}
- m_{*}\{b_n\}
=\epsilon$

By the subadditivity of the lebesgue measure and as countable sets having measure $0$.

Thus $\lbrack a_n,b_n\rbrack$ is measurable. As the countable union of measurable sets is measurable $F$ is measurable.

Comment: so this shall show for a closed set $F \in \mathbb R$ that $F$ is measurable? Then right from the top, the $F$ you are choosing is not necessarily closed, for example $     [a_n,b_n] = \big[\frac 1 n , 1 - \frac 1 n\big]$.

Comment: It is false that the union of measurable sets is measurable. For example, any set $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$, yet each $\{x\}$ is measurable. I'm sure you mean for this to be a countable union, but you must say so because that's the only reason it's true.